# Center content in a absolute positioned div

Tags: css, css-position, centering

I have an absolutly positioned element with content inside. It can be a `<h1>` or a few `<p>` tag. So I don't know the height of the content.

How can I **vertically center the content** inside the absolutly positioned `div`?

HTML :

```
<div id="absolute">
    <div class="centerd">
    <h1>helo</h1>
    <span>hi again</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#absolute {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background:yellow;
}

.centerd {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KTUM/1/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you add `display:table` to your `#absolute` div you should get what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/3KTUM/2/

Comment: This doesn't center the content .. it just makes the content *start* from the center

Comment: @ExplosionPills Seems to center the content for me - try adding more content in and you will see it stays vertically aligned, not start from the center.  You may think it starts in the center as the h1 will have natural top padding which pushes it down

Answer (score 22):

Horizontal and vertical position absolute middle.

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="obj">
  <div class="center">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the question was `how can I vertically center the content inside the absolutely positioned div?`  the absolutely positioned div is `.obj`.  your answer doesn't have `position: absolute;` on `.obj`, it doesn't work when it is applied, see this [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/4yaef3hL).

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with flexbox too:

```
#absolute {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Change your `#absolute` div to also use:

```
display:table;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KTUM/4/

Answer (score 2):

Just make the div `relative` to its `absolute` parent and use `text-align: center`, like this:

```
.centerd {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /*display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;*/
}
```

See [**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3KTUM/7/)

Comment: Your fix correctly shows how to align text elements horizontally, but the OP asked how to align things vertically.

Answer (score 1):

use text-align:center or left:50%