# How to absolutly center an overlaid Font Awesome icon?

Tags: css-position, overlay, center, font-awesome, absolute

Been trying to get a overlay effect with a icon display going.

what after is getting the icon/text absolutely centered in the grey space.
and not show with class hidden - or removing the class that displays this busy overlay.

tried margin: 0 auto   and margin:auto not much luck.
using width:100% and height in different combos has various effects

here is a base setup

https://jsfiddle.net/f8eo7y3w/1/

```css
table {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.busy-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>
        some other stuff not busy
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div>
        <table class='busy'>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="busy-indicator">
          <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>
        some other stuff not busy
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

initial start was if something could be done on the table, instead of adding a element after the table like using ::before - but i think issues with cant do html on the before/after content?

Flexible width height of table, if worked on any element would be great but div/table more then enough.

I tried using example from;

[Center content in a absolute positioned div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239030/center-content-in-a-absolute-positioned-div)

center using display:table (switch i fa icon to span text for display)

https://jsfiddle.net/39L7tqbr/

result is - busy-indicator losses background-color
and content still not vertically centered

some class missing, or am i making more complicated than needs be????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to achieve this and make the icon in the center we need to wrap the `<i>` tage inside another element another `<div>` for example, because if we try to center the `<i>` directly we will have some kind of conflict with the font-awsome animation , so we just need to center the div wraping the `<i>` tag:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="busy-indicator">
  <div>
      <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.busy-indicator > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

this will center the icon in the **busy-indicator** div

Comment: Thanks. 2 things. is the transform doing anything? and my ocd yelling it not perfectly center. changing to like 48% would only work for a handfull of sizes

Comment: transform is making sure to be centered.. top will position the top of element according to parent and transform will position it according to the element itself ... and the small difference is caused by the animation of fa-spiner

Comment: Ok got it now - minor tweak (not sure if i edit your answer or leave for you to do.) wrap the <i> icon in another element  so  <i><i class with icon and spin></i></i>   and change  css to  ".busy-indicator > i". fiddle update https://jsfiddle.net/f8eo7y3w/3/      this after 10 min trying to get he transform and animation to play togeather with out added html

Comment: i see you just need to wrap the icon <i> in another element a div or another <i> tag as you did and set the css to it .... well done :) i will edit my answer

Comment: Know this is old, but the answer here is not really complete, your code won't work out of the box without the adequate css on the parent div that's wrapped around `busy-indicator`, which should be included in your answer.

Comment: @Freddy thank you for the feedback, and feel free to edit my answer and improve it :)